# could not get version from cmake.dir

Tags: android, android-ndk, cmake-modules

when I build syc my android project it comes like this 
[image]

[image]

local.properties

[image]

How can I solve this error?

Comment: In that instruction, there isn't anything about how to import cmake file?

Comment: Should you import it in drive C or D?

Comment: I already tried  .It doesn't works.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to specify the cmake version in your build.gradle file thusly [1]

```
android {
    ...
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            ...
            // Specifies the version of CMake the Android plugin should use. You need to
            // include the path to the CMake binary of this version to your PATH
            // environmental variable.
            version "3.10.2.4988404"
        }
    }
}
```

For versions downloaded by the sdk manager, I didn't need to specify cmake.dir in my local.properties. Try deleting it entirely.

I needed to specify cmake.dir when I used a version of cmake that *wasn't* installed from Android Studio's sdk manager. Then I had to put the path to the cmake installation directory (the one containing the `bin/cmake`), not the cmake binary directory directly.

[1] Snippet is copied from https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/Cmake#version

Comment: For Linux users, this means that you have to set the `cmake.dir` parameter to `/usr/` instead of `/usr/bin/cmake`.

Comment: After adding this code snippet to the relevant file, I get an error:

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Android'.
> Could not find method android() for arguments [build] on root project 'Android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: Have you applied that android plugin to the build.gradle file?

Answer (score 2):

It was frustrating to find this silly mistake so documenting here for future visitors.

create file local.properties under your android folder if not already there with following key=value pair

**cmake.dir=<path_to_cmake_folder_without_quote_and_without_bin>**

e.g.
**cmake.dir=/use/local/cmake**

Note that following won't work

cmake.dir="/use/local/cmake"

cmake.dir=/use/local/cmake/bin

Answer (score 1):

For me, I am using the newest version of CMAKE from the source repo. It by default installs to /usr/local/bin/cmake.

The problem is that the error message never says that it is adding /bin/cmake to the path...

so for the future in your local.properties make like so:

```
cmake.dir=/usr/local/
```